# Access model version number in client when the model server loads the latest model based on incremental model numbers

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am serving two different models using the same model server via the model config file in tensorflow serving (1.3.0). Since the model version policy is set to "latest" by default, as soon as I upload a new version of a model, it gets loaded into the model server and the client can use it all fine. However, I would like my client to be aware of which version of the model it is serving. How can I propagate the model version number (which is the directory name) of the model to the client from the server? My model server code is similar to [main.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/r1.3/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/main.cc) and client code is inspired from [this example](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/r1.3/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_client.cc) provided in tensorflow serving repository.